# MPMovieController all black (no Rugby inside though :D :D)

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

)

My client asks me to read a short video as a splahscreen (as it is done especially for games for example). I googled for a bit and I think the guys use a MPMoviePlayerController with StyleControl to None (correct me if I'm wrong...)
I tried with a video from my iPhone (normally in the right format so ....), but remains black. My background is red, I see it appear at the beginning, then it is hidden by my video, which remains black and never starts.
However, I set out the frame of my video (self.view is initialized at the time), I add the player to view my self.view ... In short, I do not see what might messing around.
This is the code (with FullScreen controls to try to see, but I never see them either.
An idea by any chance?
Thx guys ;)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    MPMoviePlayerController * mMoviePlayer;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL* mMovieURL;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if (bundle) 
    {
        NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"];
        if (moviePath)
        {
            mMovieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", mMovieURL);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    mMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mMovieURL];
    //    mMoviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    mMoviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [mMoviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview: mMoviePlayer.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:mMoviePlayer];
    [mMoviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: I dropped your code into a brand new app and it worked perfectly fine in the simulator. Is the movie.mov file being copied into your application bundle? Is the movie in the correct format? Don't forget to release your movie player after it finishes playing.

Comment: Yes the movie is copied to the app folder (as I usually do), I can play it using QTX, and it comes from my iPhone4 (so it must meet the requirements right?). The only thing I didn't do is to sign my code just to test it. I'm using the latest Xcode (I think : 4.2 build 4D199) in simu 4.3 and 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try:

```
[player setFullscreen:YES];
```